# CMB2 Repeatable Group Display

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Custom Metaboxes 2 and I can't get repeatable group values to display on the front end. I have a repeatable group with a single text field.

[I used this as a guide](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#group).

I have the backend code first, followed the front end code.

```
add_action( 'cmb2_init', 'awc_register_repeatable_group_field_metabox' );

function awc_register_repeatable_group_field_metabox() {

    // Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
    $prefix = '_awc_';

/**
 * Repeatable Field Groups
 */
$cmb_group = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'           => $prefix . 'songs',
    'title'        => __( 'Track Listing', 'cmb2' ),
    'object_types' => array( 'awc_discography', ),
) );

// $group_field_id is the field id string, so in this case: $prefix . 'demo'
    $group_field_id = $cmb_group->add_field( array(
    'id'          => $prefix . 'demo',
    'type'        => 'group',
    //'description' => __( 'Generates reusable form entries', 'cmb2' ),
    'options'     => array(
        'group_title'   => __( 'Track {#}', 'cmb2' ), // {#} gets replaced by row number
        'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Track', 'cmb2' ),
        'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Track', 'cmb2' ),
        'sortable'      => true, // beta
    ),
) );

/**
 * Group fields works the same, except ids only need
 * to be unique to the group. Prefix is not needed.
 *
 * The parent field's id needs to be passed as the first argument.
 */
$cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
    'name'       => __( 'Title', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'         => 'title',
    'type'       => 'text',
) );

}
```

FRONT END:

```
$entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $prefix . 'songs', true );

foreach ( (array) $entries as $key => $entry ) {

$songtitle = '';

if ( isset( $entry['demo'] ) )
    $title = esc_html( $entry['demo'] );


// Do something with the data
echo $title; // Don't know if this is the correct method.
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have `$prefix` defined in your front end code? That's the only thing I can see being wrong there. If `$prefix` isn't defined, you're looking up the post_meta with key `songs` instead of `_awc_songs`.