# How to display Group Field metadata + Container div if it exists and display default text if fields are empty? [CMB2]

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, metadata, is-empty

I'm no programmer so I'm clueless on solutions.
I have been using [CMB2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2)
for a Portfolio/Project custom post type.

I've incorporated a slideshow that uses Group Field metadata for each slide.

On the home page there are 2 posts labeled "Empty Project" & "Test Project 1".
If you click the Empty Project you will be directed to it's single post page, there you will see a ".flexslider" div with a red background. That's the div that I would like to remove if the Group Fields are empty. My that I mean completed remove the div leaving no empty divs instead of changing the background color to white.

If you click "Test Project 1", there will be the images uploaded using Repeatable Group Fields within the "flexslider" slideshow. That is to be the result of Metafields that were saved with Metadata inside of them.

**METABOX//**
Here is the code I have used to register the repeatable fields, which allows me to insert images and captions for the slideshow.

```
add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'gallery_metabox' );
function gallery_metabox() {
$prefix = 'gallery_';

/**
 * Repeatable Field Groups
 */
$cmb_group = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'           => $prefix . 'metabox',
    'title'        => __( 'Gallery', 'cmb2' ),
    'object_types' => array( 'portfolio', ),
) );

// $group_field_id is the field id string, so in this case: $prefix . 'demo'
$group_field_id = $cmb_group->add_field( array(
    'id'          => $prefix . 'demo',
    'type'        => 'group',
    'options'     => array(
    'group_title'   => __( 'Image {#}', 'cmb2' ), // {#} gets replaced by row number
        'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Image', 'cmb2' ),
        'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Image', 'cmb2' ),
        'sortable'      => true, // beta
        'closed'     => true, // true to have the groups closed by default
    ),
) );


$cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
    'name' => __( 'Image', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'   => 'image',
    'type' => 'file',
) );

$cmb_group->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
    'name' => __( 'Image Caption', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'   => 'image_caption',
    'type' => 'text',
) );

 }
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993041/cmb2-repeatable-group-display) to display meta data for those group fields.
Everything works perfectly fine when I use this chunk of code:

**FRONT-END//**

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">

            <?php $entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gallery_demo', true );


                foreach ( (array) $entries as $key => $entry ) {

                    $img = $img_url = $caption = '';
                if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
                    $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['image_id'], 'share-pick', null, array(
                        'class' => 'thumb',
                    ) );
                }
                    if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $entry['image_id'], null );
                }
                $caption = isset( $entry['image_caption'] ) ? wpautop( $entry['image_caption'] ) : '';
                    echo '<li data-thumb="'. $img_url .'">';
                    echo $img;
                    echo $caption;
                    echo '</li>';


            } ?>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

but I would very much like to display the `.flexslider` container + metadata ONLY when data exist. If fields are empty then I would like to display default text or better yet remove the whole div itself.
I tried my best to do research but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

I've also tried this chunk of code as well:

**ATTEMPT//**

```
<?php $entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gallery_demo', true );
if(empty ($entry)) { echo ''; }
else {
   foreach ( (array) $entries as $key => $entry ) {
     echo '<div class="flexslider">';
     echo '<ul class="slides">';
   $img = $img_url = $caption = '';

   if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
     $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['image_id'], 'share-pick', null, array(
'class' => 'thumb',
   ) );
}

if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $entry['image_id'], null );
}

$caption = isset( $entry['image_caption'] ) ? wpautop( $entry['image_caption'] ) : '';
    echo '<li data-thumb="'. $img_url .'">';
    echo $img;
    echo $caption;
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';      
    }   
  }
 ?>
```

The only good thing about the code above is that it definitely removes the div when metafield is empty but if the metadata DOES exist the div is still gone.

**EDIT//** I tried using "@stweb" code in the answers below:

```
$entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gallery_demo', true );

foreach ( (array) $entries as $key => $entry ) {
   if(empty($entry)){
      continue;
   }
   echo '<div class="flexslider">';
   echo '<ul class="slides">';
   $img = $img_url = $caption = '';

   if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
     $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['image_id'], 'share-pick',   
   null, array(    'class' => 'thumb', ) );
   }

   if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
     $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $entry['image_id'], null );
   }

   $caption = isset( $entry['image_caption'] ) ? wpautop(    
   $entry['image_caption'] ) : '';
   echo '<li data-thumb="'. $img_url .'">';
   echo $img;
   echo $caption;
   echo '</li>';
   echo '</ul>';
   echo '</div>';      
}
```

but nothing happens...the red div just sits there instead of disappearing.

I'd basically like to figure out how I can display the first chunk of code ONLY if images were uploaded to Group Field and if not then display nothing at all not even the container div.

Can anyone please explain where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'gallery_demo', true );

foreach ( (array) $entries as $key => $entry ) {
   if(empty($entry)){
      continue;
   }
   echo '<div class="flexslider">';
   echo '<ul class="slides">';
   $img = $img_url = $caption = '';

   if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
     $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['image_id'], 'share-pick',   
   null, array(    'class' => 'thumb', ) );
   }

   if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
     $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $entry['image_id'], null );
   }

   $caption = isset( $entry['image_caption'] ) ? wpautop(    
   $entry['image_caption'] ) : '';
   echo '<li data-thumb="'. $img_url .'">';
   echo $img;
   echo $caption;
   echo '</li>';
   echo '</ul>';
   echo '</div>';      
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
foreach ( (array) $entries as $key => $entry ) {
    if ( !isset( $entry['image_id'] )  ||  $entry['image_id']  == ''  ) {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<div class="flexslider">';
    echo '<ul class="slides">';
    $img = $img_url = $caption = '';

    if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
       $img = wp_get_attachment_image( $entry['image_id'], 'share-pick', 
       null, array(    'class' => 'thumb', ) );
    } 

    if ( isset( $entry['image_id'] ) ) {
       $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $entry['image_id'], null );
    }

    $caption = isset( $entry['image_caption'] ) ? wpautop(         
    $entry['image_caption'] ) : '';
    echo '<li data-thumb="'. $img_url .'">';
    echo $img;
    echo $caption;
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';      
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for the issue I was having, thanks anyway.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't remove the container div if fields are empty.

Comment: Do you need to show container if both image_id and image_caption is set?

Comment: Yes but if those fields are empty there will be no need to display the container.

Comment: I've updated my question and included a test site link so you can see the issue. There is a post that has empty fields for both image_id and image_caption...on the empty post the div remains in position. On the Test Post 1 the image_id and image_caption fields data were saved which displays the slideshow. I hope the test site can help with a better/revised answer :)

Comment: Does exactly what I need it to do! Thank you very much !

Comment: Happy to hear it works for you. In this code just at start of foreach loop we check the $entry['image_id']. You can also add checking of $entry['image_caption'] in in the same way.